# Sikuli and Python: Selecting from multiple images, but only once

Tags: python, sikuli

Successfully attempting to find objects on the screen, see if they exist, and if so, select them. Using the Sikuli library to run this little automation. I search the screen, decide if an image exists (from a list) and choose any that are there, then want to `click("go")`. If none of the list items are there, it would execute `click("go.png")` and carry on. If there are any list items there, it clicks it *just once*, and then executes the `click("go.png")` Right now, it loops and forever selects found images, back and forth, select/deselect.

```
imageFiles = ["one.png", "two.png", "three,png"]

for imageFile in imageFiles:
  if exists(imageFile):
    click(imageFile)

click("go.png")
```

How can I make the selection a single event, without deselecting it, before executing `click("go.png")`

Comment: I don't completely understand the problem, but have you considered adding a `break` statement?

Comment: Yes. Then the execution just sits there until the implicit time out (60s).

Comment: This sounds strange. The for loop should iterate only once within the imageFiles range. I see no reason why it would repeat itself.. Is this piece of code wrapped into anything else?